# Formatting html inside a td element using webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a `DataTable` that's being bound to a `GridView` -

```
DataTable dt = GetTable();
myGridView.DataSource = dt;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

In one of the DataTable columns, `Sentence`. I have a string which may contain a search term, `Word`

I was hoping to highlight any instances of `Word` in each row in that column with a different colour background, so tried this:

```
DataTable dt = GetTable();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dr("Sentence") = dr("Sentence").ToString().Replace(Word, "<span style='background-color: #ccc;'>" + Word + "</span>")
}

myGridView.DataSource = dt;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

This replaces the text but it's just left as text, it doesn't convert to the inline html styling that I wanted.

e.g. the sentence `I want my searchword to be highlighted` just becomes `I want my <span style='background-color: #ccc;'>searchword</span> to be highlighted`

This has something to do with preformatting I think but when I google that it gives me results for white-space and if I use `pre` element instead of `td` it just makes everything courier.

The asp.net view for that column looks like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Sentence" HeaderText="Sentence" SortExpression="Sentence" Visible="false">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="preformatted" />
    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

And the preformatted class is currently just `white-space: pre-line;`

Comment: DataTable is a server-side data container. It has nothing at all to do with HTML. It would be better if you used a `List<T>` with a strongly typed object actually. Where is the ASP.NET code that generates the HTML table? Are you using WebForms, MVC, Razor Pages?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Added that to the question

Comment: When ASP.NET renders data into HTML *all* the data is HTML encoded, both to prevent breaking HTML by injecting unexpected characters like `>` *and* to prevent script injection. You can't modify HTML formatting by changing the data, you have to do this in the rendering code

Comment: So I could do it in the bound data once it's in the gridview instead?

Comment: I'm probably best off using some js to do this :/

Comment: You should read the docs and tutorials on GridView, especially how to create item templates for fields. The example [in this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data#add-a-gridview-control) uses a GridView with  templates for example. WebForms is so old there are a *ton* of good docs, courses, tutorials and books on this.

Comment: No you aren't - any JavaScript you use is going to do the same thing a template would do, probably using .... templates, only with a lot more code. Which would probably conflict with the rest of the rendered HTML. After all, you're still generating *static* HTML. It would make sense to switch to JavaScript if you wanted to create an SPA

Comment: Is this a new project? Why use WebForms on a new project? Why not ASP.NET Core MVC or Razor pages?

Comment: lol this is far from a new project it's about 13 years old. I'm just tasked with some minor updates on it while it's being replaced.

Comment: In which case adding Javascript is the worst possible solution and definitely not minor. Modify that field's template and add the span. Although, the GridView **already** allows you to format the entire field either by setting explicit properties like Font and color, or setting the CSS class. You could change the CSS class or create a *new* one for highlighted, preformatted text. That's what you would do if you used just HTML and Javascript after all, you wouldn't go around explicitly changing element style properties. I hope

Comment: Yeah I didn't want the whole table cell highlighted, just the word in the sentence. I'm not sure how to use the template to do this but I'm trying to figure it out. I don't have models for the data or anything, it's just a string that could be anything.

Comment: ok well I'm nearly there with the `TemplateField`, I just don't know how to pass the search term to the `Label` inside

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was able to do it using TemplateField, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos' advice I was able to do this using a `TemplateField` - it's old hat and well-documented WebForms I know, but the answer might still prove useful to someone.

I replaced a boundfield

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Sentence" HeaderText="Sentence" SortExpression="Sentence" Visible="false">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="preformatted" />
    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

with a template field

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sentence" SortExpression="Sentence" Visible="true" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Replace(Eval("Sentence"), wordSearched, "<span class=""high"">" & wordSearched & "</span>") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Where I had to define `wordSearched` as a public or protected string variable in the code-behind.